# My Grep command is not working at all `grep -orE "<Table[\n\r\s]+showFilterBar=\{false\}" ./app`

Tags: bash, grep

```
<Table[\n\r\s]+showFilterBar=\{false\}
```

This regex when pasted in VSCode search works but when I grep it does not. I have also tried:

```
<Table[\n\r\s]\+showFilterBar=\{false\}
<Table[\n\r\s]\+
```

I want to basically find all Table components when `showFilterBar={false}` prop is used and set to false.

Comment: Regular expressions are not the right tools for parsing HTML, which is not a regular language. Obligatory link: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/7552

Comment: i have a app directory which has a lot of JSX in different files i need to find all instances of <Table where showFilterBar is false. is there a another way where i do not have to grep using regex?

Comment: If your html is valid XML, you can use an XML processing tool, such as [tag:xmlstarlet]. Also, please review your requirements: you want to set it to "false" when it is already "false"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` doesn't support `\s` for whitespace. Use `[:space:]` instead, or list out all of the whitespace characters individually.

```
grep -E '<Table[[:space:]]+showFilterBar={false}'
grep -E '<Table[ \t\r]+showFilterBar={false}'
```

I've omitted `\n` since `grep` only searches one line at a time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. 
I tried `grep -orE "<Table[\t\r]+showFilterBar=\{false\}" app/` and `grep -orE "<Table[\t\r]+showFilterBar" ./app`
Both of them did not work.

Comment: The space is crucial. `[ \t\r]` with a space after the opening bracket not `[\t\r]`.